# Trying to calculate the integral limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_{-\sqrt n}^{\sqrt n}\left (1 - \frac{x^2}{2n}\right)^ndx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

How to calculate following integral:

> $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-\sqrt{n}}^{\sqrt{n}}{\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n}\right)^n}dx$$
>   Prove that this integral exists and compute its value.

I just do not how start it. It is in **real analysis**, but I did not see any relation with real analsis.

Comment: Why don't you just evaluate the integral for fixed $n$ and then compute the limit?

Comment: And of course, it has a relation with real analysis...!!

Comment: I guess the question becomes easier if one labels it "freshman calculus" instead of "real analysis".

Comment: @Guest et al., the OP has edited the integrand.  It's no longer quite so simple.

Comment: See [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integrals may be written $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_n(x)\, dx$, where $f_n(x) = 1_{[-\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n}]}(x)\cdot(1 - \frac{x^2}{2n})^n$. Now since $1 - \frac{x^2}{2n} \le e^{-x^2/2n}$, $|f_n(x)| \le e^{-x^2/2}$. Furthermore, $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x) = e^{-x^2/2}$ and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\, dx$ is finite. By the dominated convergence theorem, your limit is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\, dx = \sqrt{2\pi}$.